# Firefox NPAPI plugin on Windows

Tags: firefox, plugins, npapi

I'm trying to implement a NPAPI plugin for Firefox on Windows, using MingW to compile. Everything work fine during the compiling, but the plugin doesn't work well when it is loaded by Firefox. The browser detects some parameters of plugin like name and author, for example, but it doesn't get methods and properties correctly (they aren't recognized when called by a javascript code). The plugin works without any problem on Linux, but not on Windows.

Code: http://pastebin.com/eSDdxrMr

Comment: And here is a version that actually has syntax highlighting enabled so you can read it: http://pastebin.com/TujgHnYS

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that just because it detects the plugin name and mimetype doesn't mean that it's loading the DLL; on windows those are stored as string resources.  Are any of the entrypoints getting called? Does your logfile get created?

If none of the entrypoints are getting hit at all, check to make sure you're actually exporting them; do you have a .def file? Does it have the entrypoints correct?

[FireBreath](http://www.firebreath.org) uses this for the .def:

- https://github.com/firebreath/FireBreath/blob/master/gen_templates/FireBreathWin.def

Here are the windows entrypoints:

- https://github.com/firebreath/FireBreath/blob/master/src/PluginAuto/Win/np_winmain.cpp

Comment: It looks like nothing is called. The log file is not created and no properties is able to be got.

Comment: Okay; so take a look at the files I referenced and see if you can figure out why the DLL is not being loaded.  Another common problem is if you're linking to a .lib file that requires a DLL to be present and the DLL is not there. You can often find insight into that using "dependency walker" (depends.exe), though ieshims.dll will often show up as missing when it isn't.